# MWS Developer access for PII personal identifiable Information Revoked - Buyersname, phone, Addresses are coming blank

Tags: api, amazonsellercentral, pii

We are using Amazon Seller account and have been using MWS API for last 10 months. However this is the first time we got this issue.

```
1. All of our API is getting failed.
2. BuyerName, Addresses, phone are not coming from the MWS API.
3. In the XML, The above tags are missing.
```

What i need to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced this issue and we co-ordinate with amazon MWS operation Support team at https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/. They suggested upon checking, that role was revoked and due to which some Amazon MWS operations and reports do not return certain data.

They suggested to fill the below form from the given link in order to receive Personally Identifiable Information (PII).
https://sellercentral.amazon.co.uk/mws/register/developer-info

But upon clicking this URL, we found access related issue and then the MWS operation team passed this issue to Developer Registration and Assessment forms team to help us in resolving the issue.

Comment: Where did you connected with MWS Team?

Comment: Please check the below screencast where we found the chat option to chat with MWS operation team or create a case https://www.screencast.com/t/kC9zvwek4px